# Passing Cloud Storage custom metadata into Cloud Storage Notification

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub, google-api-python-client

We have a Python script that copies/creates files in a GCS bucket.

```
# let me know if my setting of the custom-metadata is correct    
blob.metadata = { "file_capture_time": some_timestamp_var }
blob.upload(...)
```

We want to configure the bucket such that it generates Cloud Storage notifications whenever an object is created. We also want the custom metadata above to be passed along with the Pub/Sub message to the topic and use that as an ordering key in the Subscription side. How can we do this?

Comment: Please let me know if the below information was useful.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended [way to receive notification](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/notification#options) when an event occurs on the intended GCS bucketis to create a [Cloud Pub/Sub topic for new objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications#format) and to configure your GCS bucket to publish messages to that topic when new objects are created.
Initially, make sure you've activated the Cloud Pub/Sub API, and use the `gsutil` command similar to below:

```
gsutil notification create -f json -e OBJECT_FINALIZE gs://example-bucket
```

The -e specifies that you're only interested in OBJECT_FINALIZE messages (objects being created)
The -f specifies that you want the payload of the messages to be the object metadata for the JSON API
The -m specifies a key:value attribute that is appended to the set of attributes sent to Cloud Pub/Sub for all events associated with this notification config.
You may specify this parameter multiple times to set multiple attributes.
The [full Firebase example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/deb2a8a18289b3f7caa816c8b35d863410133585/quickstarts/thumbnails/functions/index.js#L34) which explains the parsing the filename and other info from its context/data with
Here is a [good example with a similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62121161/file-payload-in-google-cloud-function-bucket-triggered) context.